# Snapshot dosn't have data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code
I guess that the app doesn't connect to firebase at all

> If I put the material app in the else that have "There is no data from Firebase" the app will get too much errors that I can count (there is some exampels).

*══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞═══════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call
Firebase.initializeApp()*

*Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value.
The exception occurred during the creation of type Register.*
My Code:

```dart
 void main() {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        ));
       runApp(const AppRestart(child: MyApp(),));
      }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

    late Future<FirebaseApp> firebaseApp;
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp();
    }

      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FutureBuilder(
      future: firebaseApp,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        // if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        //   return const ConfigMaterial(child: AppLoading(loading: ChoiceLoading.page),);
        // }

        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

          if(snapshot.hasData) {

            return MultiProvider(
                providers: providers,
                builder: (context, child) { 
                  // provider theme
                  final ControllerTheme manageTheme =Provider.of<ControllerTheme>(context);
                  // check theme
                  manageTheme.sharedTheme();
                  return MaterialApp(
                  onGenerateTitle: (context) => "shelf system",
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  title: "shelf system",
                  initialRoute: "/",
                  routes: AppRoutes.route,
                  theme: AppThemeChoose.lightTheme(context),
                  darkTheme: AppThemeChoose.DarkTheme(context),
                  );
                },
                );
          }
          else {
            return const ConfigMaterial(child: Text("There is no data from Firebase",style: 
    TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30),),);
            
          }
         }

         else {
           return const ConfigMaterial(child: Text("Error while connect to Firebase",style: 
           TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30),),);
            }
      
         }
      );
      }
     }
```

*Please help**

Answer (score 0):

```
  void main() {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    


  try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        /// File generated by FlutterFire CLI.
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
  } on FirebaseException catch ( e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
     

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    ));
   runApp(const AppRestart(child: MyApp(),));
  }

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {



  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiProvider(
            providers: providers,
            builder: (context, child) { 
              // provider theme
              final ControllerTheme manageTheme =Provider.of<ControllerTheme>(context);
              // check theme
              manageTheme.sharedTheme();
              return MaterialApp(
              onGenerateTitle: (context) => "shelf system",
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: "shelf system",
              initialRoute: "/",
              routes: AppRoutes.route,
              theme: AppThemeChoose.lightTheme(context),
              darkTheme: AppThemeChoose.DarkTheme(context),
              );
            },
            );
  }
 }
```

Comment: please add it to code